# How can I implement youtube App like layout in android 2.3?

Tags: android

How can  implement youtube App like layout in android 2.3? I mean on tapping to right side , we can see our profile,history etc with half of the main screen on the right side .See [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qnmezbqpu53h0rs/Screenshot_2013-03-22-15-31-12.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its called `multi pane layout`(http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/multi-pane-layouts.html), you create them using `Fragments` (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html). Good luck